# Building an Android app, UI goes blank after a second with some BinderProxy error

Tags: android, user-interface, screen, visibility

I've been building an app from last couple of days now. I'm getting this weird error, where after opening the app, the whole screen goes white and I can't do anything. I'm getting my logs normally although. Seems like the whole app is working fine just the UI goes blank and I think it has something to do with the following log that I get.

04-14 13:09:43.880: I/art(17944): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5065(575KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(584KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 38MB/54MB, paused 8.631ms total 49.204ms

04-14 13:09:49.905: I/Timeline(17944): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.packageName time:8607601

04-14 13:09:50.000: A/Home(17944): isFinishing = false

04-14 13:09:50.040: D/Activity(17944): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse

04-14 13:09:50.040: D/Activity(17944): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue

04-14 13:09:50.150: I/Timeline(17944): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@a363fd9 time:8607846

04-14 13:09:50.220: V/ActivityThread(17944): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3fd6d07f token=android.os.BinderProxy@47236cc {com.packageName/com.packageName.Home}} show : false

Please help me out. Going crazy over here. Can't figure out what it is.

Some other things which might help you guys to understand my problem are:

1. I'm using Facebook login in an activity and it only happens when I switch from the Facebook Activity to this activity(mostly)
2. The activity is recreating itself which causes this bug.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Is there any Service that you are going to Bind at the time of loading Application UI.

Comment: I would post the code, but I don't know what thing is causing this problem, so not sure which code to post, can't post the whole application.

I'm using the SensorEventListener, Wizrocket analytics and Quickblox SDK in this activity. I think it is one of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned I was using SensorEventListener, I was using that in an activity previous to this one too. And I hadn't unregistered the listener before finishing that activity which caused this error. But thanks everybody for pointing me to the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
The crash is because the binder you're getting back is an instance of BinderProxy, not your local binder class. This usually happens because your activity is attempting to bind to a service that is not in the same process. When binding across process boundaries, an instance of BinderProxy is used instead of the actual instance (since that's in a different process).

Try this

if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Didn't help, I even logged isFinishing(), I always got false only, but still got the same error. If someone can explain me what does this exactly do, I might be able to debug it myself.

Answer (score -1):

1. Have you used setContentView method properly to set layout
2. Declared activity in menifest
3. Please check in you class, may be there was any null reference of view or context

Comment: 1. Yes, and if I wouldn't have done any of the rest, it would crash, its not crashing, just the screen goes white.